# How to interpret Zero-Length XML Element Content?

Tags: xml

Given an element with zero-length content **`<foo></foo>`**, is the textual value of **foo** `""` or `null`?

Does the answer depend on whether the containing document is being interpreted by some schema or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered an empty string.  There is no concept of "null" in XML.  There is a "nil", which is specified as an attribute like:

```
<foo xsi:nil="true" />
```

There is also the option of simply omitting the element, which may be considered "null-like" to the consumer of the XML.

For example, JAXB marshals both "nil" and a missing element to a Java `null`, and you can configure how it behaves in the reverse scenario.